# Parameterise $y^2-x^2=1$ - not possible.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I'm doing stuff from a book and it has just spoke of the importance of not parameterising half a curve (with the example of a circle).

However I am not sure what to do.

First of all $\cosh^2-\sinh^2=1$ so I could try $y=\cosh(t),x=\sinh(t)$ but this is just one part of the solution (I'd need another curve with the same x but $y=-\cosh(t)$)

I also know that (because it is two curves) it isn't continuous (it has 2 continuous and smooth parts) this makes me think of $\tan$, if I can map tan's discontinuities to the jump I'm fine.

So if I use $x=\sinh(\tan(t))$ and $y=\frac{t}{|t|}\cosh(\tan(t))$ over the range $-\pi$ to $\pi$ I get the entire curve.

I don't think this is in the spirit of the question though, the point of the question is to "parameterise the following level curves" - should I just give two solutions? A parameterisation is (according to the book) a map from $(a,b)$, my domain has holes in it (where tan jumps) and MUST have holes in it.

What does the question want?

Comment: It is artificial to use tan to try to make it look like a parametrization on a single interval, when it is not.  It is not connected, so you need two parts, no big deal.  I don't see exactly what the question is.

Comment: So the answer wants two curves? That answers the question @JonasMeyer and yes it is artificial, that's why I asked.

Comment: $\left(\tan(t),\sec(t)\right)$

Comment: I don't grasp the meaning of not being possible to "parameterize" a curve.  Possibly the "picture" of the half circle would shed some light on the issue, which seems to be roughly that the hyperbola has two branches, so "jumping" from one branch to the other involves a point in the parameter domain where a discontinuity occurs.  But there are many ways to parameterize a circle (or a half circle), so more clarity is needed.

Comment: @DanUznanski how did you arrive at that? Just know your identities?

Comment: Mostly.  Your stuff with $\cosh$ doesn't work well because a single branch of the function ends up taking up an infinite domain in both directions.  Clearly we have to cover both and the easiest way is something that will do so in a finite piece of $t$, which means periodic, which sends us straight to trig functions, and one of the rejiggerings of the Pythagorean identity is $\sec^2(\theta)-\tan^2(\theta)=1$.

Comment: @Alec: The answer to what exactly? I don't whether it "wants" two curves, but there are two curves.  How do you define curve?

Answer (score 0):

A first glance tells us a whole lot:  We have two lobes of the standard, vertically opening hyperbola.  If we want to cover the entire thing, there must be at least one discontinuity in our parametrization.

Now, we have two options.  The first is that we act like the function is periodic, which means constructing this out of trigonometric functions.  The second is that we act like the function is not periodic -- that instead we place a single discontinuity at a single point.

### Periodic

After a brief look, it is clear that we can choose $x(t)=\tan(t)$, because the two branches both cover all values for $x$, and do so without turning back on itself.  This gives us:
$$y(t)^2 - \tan(t)^2=1$$
$$y(t)^2=1+\frac{\sin(t)^2}{\cos(t)^2}$$
$$=\frac{\cos(t)^2}{\cos(t)^2}+\frac{\sin(t)^2}{\cos(t)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\cos(t)^2}=\sec(t)^2$$
$$y(t)=\sec(t)$$
And that's the whole story.  $f(t)=(\tan(t),\sec(t))$

### Non-periodic

This one's more technical.

First let's assign some obvious values:  $f(0)$ should be undefined; we'll pick $f(1)=(0, 1)$, and $f(-1)=(0,-1)$.  We'll want $x(t)$ to be either even or odd, and $y(t)$ to be odd.  Furthermore, we'll make the choice of $y(t)=y\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$, and $x(t)=-x\left(\frac{1}{t}\right).$  This gives us log-even and log-odd functions:  $u=\log(t)$ gives $y_{log}(u)=y_{log}(-u)$ and $x_{log}(u)=-x_{log}(-u)$.  So, do we have even and odd functions that are nice to take the log of the argument with?  Yes.  The odd one is $\sinh$.  Let's see where it gets us.
$$\sinh(u)=\sinh(\log(t))$$
$$=\frac{e^{\log(t)}-e^{-\log(t)}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{2}$$
$$x(t)=\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{2}$$
Neato.  Now plug that back in to see what we get for $y$:
$$y(t)^2-x(t)^2=1$$
$$y(t)^2=1+\left(\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{2}\right)^2$$
$$=1+\frac{t^2-2+\frac{1}{t^2}}{4}$$
$$=\frac{t^2+2+\frac{1}{t^2}}{4}$$
$$=\left(\frac{t+\frac{1}{t}}{2}\right)^2$$
$$y(t)=\frac{t+\frac{1}{t}}{2}$$

So, as a non-periodic function, a parametrization is $f(t)=\left(\frac{1-1/t}{2}, \frac{1+1/t}{2}\right)$

These are, of course, not the only parameterizations.  But they're the most convenient.